# PHP&AJAX: How to call dynamically method with unknown number of argument

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, methods, loading

I wrote general class Loader, which I use for controlling and loading PHP classes ("autoloading"), ect. Part of code, simplified:

PHP file:

```
 namespace Ajax;

 require_once '../Loader.php';

 class Loader extends \Loader{

 static public function getAjaxResponse($Post){

    if (!\Checker::isClassName($Post['className']) || !\Checker::isMethodName($Post['method']) ){
        return '';
    }

    Loader::loadClass($Post['className']);
    $class = '\\'.$Post['className'];

    $handler = array($class, $Post['method']);
    if (is_callable($handler) ){
        $oClass = new $class(true);
        return $oClass->$Post['method']($Post['params']);
    }        
   }
 }

 new Loader;
 echo Loader::getAjaxResponse($_POST);
```

JS file:

```
 var requestData = {
   className : 'Menu',
   method : 'assignItemToMenu',
   params : { IdItem: $('input[name="IdItem"]').val(), IdParent:$('select[name="IdParent"]').val() }
 };

 if ($('#itemsSortOrder').children().length == 0){
  $.extend(requestData.params, {addButtons : true} );
 }

 $.post('../classRepository/Ajax/Loader.php?open=' + $_GET['open'], requestData)
    .success(function(data){
       document.write(data);
       window.alert(data);
    })
    .error(function(){
       window.alert('Retrieving data failed.');
    });
```

When does it work? When you send only one param in AJAX request, JS code contain:

```
 var requestData = {
   className : 'Vocabulary',
   method : 'getReport',
   params : $('#report').val()
 };
```

When it doesn't work? When you need send more then 1 param. I tried to use call_user_func_array(), but it doesnt work with $this-> inside object, the method must be static. I tried to use reflection, but without any success.

I know a hell way, how to do this: eval(); but this is more evil than eval :)) , code would look like this:

```
 $params = array();
 foreach ($_POST['params'] as $param){
    if (is_string($param) ){
       $params[] = '"'.$param.'"';
    }
    else{
       $params[] = $param;
    }
 }
 $params = implode(',',$params);

 $oClass = new $class;
 eval ('$oClass->$_POST["method"]('.$params.')');
```

Does anyone know of you, how to solve it?

Comment: Try to rewrite your question and focus more on the current problem rather than your overall goal. Post only the code which is causing the problem, write here any output error messages you got from either PHP or JS debugger. Merely saying "it doesn't work" isn't enough information, and I know you posted some code but I doubt many people understand what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried that didn't work, but this should successfully replace your `eval()`:

```
call_user_func_array(array($oClass, $_POST["method"]), $params);
```